# django debug toolbar problem with the failed to load module script

Tags: python, django, debugging

I have been installing djang-debug-toolbar but it is not showing in the chrome developer console, it displays the following error.

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

1. I have installed pip django debug toolbar using pip in pycharm
2. I have changed the setting in `settings.py`
   [image]
3. Also I have changed the `urls.py` in the project folder

[image]

4. I went in the registry of the windows to check on the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js\Content Type from text/plain to`
   but there is no Content Type folder under the folder .js
   [image]

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You need 'Content Type' key in '.js' folder.
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8Qle.png)